# PendingIntent null when trying to call it from a class

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, alarm

Im bulding an alarm clock, and I got a pendingIntent that should snooze the alarm. The same code worked great when it was in the Activity. I change some things, and now its in a different class. I get a nullpointerExecption. (The contractor gets the context from the activity.

Snooze function:

```
public void settingNewIntentForSnooze() {
    PendingIntent alarmPendingIntent=null;
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    // new alarm after the snooze.
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + snoozeTime);
    Intent snoozeIntent = new Intent(context, Alarm_Reciver.class);
    snoozeIntent.putExtra("click_status", true);
    //add that to try to solve the problem...
    snoozeIntent.setAction("Snooze");
    alarmPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, snoozeIntent, alarmPendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    //tells to phone to set the alarm
    alarm_manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), alarmPendingIntent);
}
```

AlarmPage activity(the code that creats the variable) :

```
snooze= new Snooze(this,alarm_manager);
```

AlarmReciver:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("in alarm reciver","in alarm reciver");
    Intent service_intent= new Intent(context, RingtonePlayingService.class);//intent for the service ringtone playing
    boolean button_status = intent.getExtras().getBoolean("click_status");
    service_intent.putExtra("click_status", button_status);//passing button status
    context.startService(service_intent);//start the ringtone service
}
```

The error:

```
09-17 18:25:25.564 1563-1563/com.example.itay.newfrindlyalarm E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            Process: com.example.itay.newfrindlyalarm, PID: 1563
                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.AlarmManager.set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)' on a null object reference
                                                                                at com.example.itay.newfrindlyalarm.Snooze.settingNewIntentForSnooze(Snooze.java:60)
                                                                                at com.example.itay.newfrindlyalarm.Snooze.operate(Snooze.java:44)
                                                                                at com.example.itay.newfrindlyalarm.AlarmPage.operateSnooze(AlarmPage.java:88)
                                                                                at com.example.itay.newfrindlyalarm.AlarmPage$3.onClick(AlarmPage.java:68)
                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24697)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
enter code here
```

Comment: Why do you define the `alarmPendingInten=null` in the first line, but then overrride it later when you canl `getBroadcast`? that's bad style :)

Comment: What's the value of `context` inside the `settingNewIntentForSnooze` method? Does it have a good value?

Comment: Please add your error message. It is hard to debug code without seeing the error :)

Comment: @KonstantinSchubert - I just tried to "define" it to null after the exception, I thought that its meaningless but I'm a nooby, so I gave it a shot. thanks for the comment ! settingNewIntentForSnooze gets its context from AlarmPage in the contractor(I added that line from it). AlarmPage is the activity that create the snooze class and uses it.
I will add my error message.. I though that null exception is enough, as I said, I'm a nooby.. thank you for your patients..

Comment: We are all Noobs in most things. One tip: Try to avoid setting things to `null`. Whenever you are tempted using `null`somewhere, try to think of a way to avoid it. It will make your code cleaner because carrying around variables that are null is like having empty milk cartons in your fridge. It just leads to frustration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by the error message, is it possible that `alarm_manager` is `null`? If you initialize `AlarmManager` properly, does the error go away?

Comment: yes, I just created an snooze object before I initialize the AlarmManager I entered to his constructor.. I spend two hours on this error, and now I see how simple it is.. Thank you very much!